# Prevention of Temporary Word File Creation while Opening a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA Code that opens a word document and process that document. When it opens a word document , it also creates a temporary word file.If my document name is "Statistical Data.doc" , when it opens the file, it creates a temporary document with a name "~$atistical Data.doc".

I have made one condition so that this temporary file not get processed.But it takes time as if i run for large number of documents, it creates same number of temporary files and process completes only after checking the condition.

Is there any way to prevent the creation of temporary document .

Comment: Rather than suppressing file creation, why not just check the file name for "~$" before processing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you close the file when it's done being processed, shouldn't that solve your problem? Like open file->process file->save file->next. Post your code and I'll be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to stop Word creating temporary files. They're necessary in order for Word to work with a document. Among other things, it's where Word stores the lists for "Undo". It also does other work in the background. If a document is closed correctly and Word does not crash, then Word will take care of removing these files, itself. If that's not happening, then your code is not releasing Word correctly or your configuration is damaged.